# HQL inline query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Specific to hibernate i am newbie. so please pardon me as if i am asking basic stuff. Though i can directly use SQL and make things complete I wants to convert the herewith mentioned complex inline query in HQL. Can anyone Quickly guide me how to do it. i.e which features do i need to use etc.

```
Select c.DOCUMENT_TITLE_EN, d.* From 
(Select a.*, b.AOB_SUPPORTED_DOCUMENT_ID from
(Select act.* 
from ACTIVITIES act inner join CATEGORIES cat
on act.CATEGORIES_ID=cat.CATEGORIES_ID 
Where cat.AOB_CATEGORIES_ID in (1) 
and act.USER_TYPE= '1') a left outer join ACTIVITY_ATTACHMENT b
on a.ACTIVITIES_ID = b.ACTIVITIES_ID) d     
Left Outer Join SUPPORTED_DOCUMENT c 
on d.SUPPORTED_DOCUMENT_ID = c.SUPPORTED_DOCUMENT_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create hibernate entity for each table and java attributes for database columns.

Then in hql all you need is to replace table names with entity names and column names with attributes names.

Answer (score 0):

use this method ...
session.createQuery();

Comment: create java class with attributes base on your table column_name and then use

session.createQuery("select* from Your_Class_name");

Like..

@entity`enter code here`
@table("Table_name")
public class Test{
private int id;
private String name;

setter/get
}

now.    session_object.createQuery("select column_name from Test");